# How to create category for textField

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield, objective-c-category

I want to create category which works same as

```
 - (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range
 replacementString:(NSString *)string
```

The advantage of this method is it doesn't allows user to enter invalid character.

Is it possible to manage this method in category of TextFiled.

The below code validate the textfield, Anyone can help me to create category of it.

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{

 if (textField == NameText )
    {
        if ([string isEqualToString:@""])
        {
            NSString *originalString = textField.text;
            NSInteger newLength = [textField.text length];
            if (originalString.length > newLength)
                NameText.text = [originalString substringToIndex:newLength];
            return YES;
        }
        else
        {
            BOOL canEdit=NO;

            NSCharacterSet *myCharSet = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"1234567890-/:;()&@\".,?!'[]{}#%^*+=_\\|~<>$£₹€•"];
            for (int i = 0; i < [string length]; i++)
            {
                unichar c = [string characterAtIndex:i];
                if ([myCharSet characterIsMember:c])
                {
                    canEdit=NO;
                }
                else
                {
                    if ([NameText.text length] >= 10)
                    {
                        canEdit=NO;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        canEdit=YES;
                    }
                }
            }
            return canEdit;
        }
    }
 return YES;
}
```

> Note : I don't want to create any custom method which shows an alert
>   when user enters invalid data. I want that user will not able to enter
>   invalid data.

Comment: You want a UITextField extension to act as its own delegate? I do not thinky you can do that by using an extension but you could subclass UITextField and directly refer to this subclass from IB (Storyboard Editor).

Comment: not getting your point, Brief it.

Comment: All right. Why do you want to do that in a category? Is this just about reusing the solution? Then subclass UITextField and in the subclass' init mehtod let the delegate refer to self. Your subclass of course needs to conform to the protocol UITextFieldDelegate. You cannot do that in any reusable way in an extension nor in a category without further lines of code wherever you reuse it.

Comment: Can you please brief your suggestion by answering my question with code ?

Comment: If I can do it with subclass then it also fine with me, but If you know how to do it, please answer this question

Answer (score 0):

```
@interface myLimitedTextView: UITextView <UITextViewDelegate>

@end

@implementation 

-(instancetype) init {  // not sure from the top of my head if there are more init variancies to be overwritten. 

  self = [super init];
  if (self) {
     self.delegate = self; //Do not set a delegate in IB!
  }
}

// overwriting getters and setters may even be more efficient 

- (void) setDelegate {
// You may want to NSLog here something to see, if the setter is called
  self.delegate = self; 
}

- (id <UITextFieldDelegate) getDelegate {
  return self;
}

- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
  //Do your stuff here 
  return YES;
}

@end
```

Comment: I can't idenify textfied == NameTextFiled in above code , becuase I had defined textfiled in another class

Comment: Then use `if (textfield == self) ...`. BTW `NameText` is not an appropriate name for a variable. You should use `nameText` instead. However, in the above code just refer to `textfield` or `self`